# Ubuntu Server 20.10 doesn't allow boot device selection

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.10, usb-installation

So I decided to install Ubuntu server 20.10 instead of my broken Linux Mint and avoid the buggy UIs, but the first 3 evenings with the Server Installer are extremely frustrating: it doesn't allow to select a "Boot device" and doesn't even tell me what is wrong or what it expects.

All I want is to keep the existing partition of Linux Mint for reference and migration reasons. This disqualifies the "auto" function -which erases the entire drive.

When I would use the "auto" storage configuration, it proposes the following:
USED DEVICES:
ubuntu-gv with ubuntu-lv as ext4

CT250MXzzzzz

- partition 1, 1MB new, bios_grub
- partition 2, 1GB new, ext4 mounted at /boot
- partition 3, PV of LVM volume group

Now, in the "manual" it states that editing is not possible and we shall use a shell, which I did and created partitions with fdisk:

- partition 1, 1MB, unused ESP
- partition 2, 1GB, unused ext4
- partition 4, 92GB, unused ext4

I can select the partition 2 as mounted /boot, partition 3 as root, but for some reason though "Use as boot device" is still not possible on the device. If I select "edit" on the ESP partition it explains "if this disk is selected as boot device Grub will be installed onto this". Fine, what do I miss?

BTW: What can I do to "refresh" the storage configuration data. Currently, each time I drop to Shell and use fdisk, I need to reboot as the installer keeps the "old" setup...

Answer (score 0):

Got it installed without removing the partition:

> partition 1 has to be created as 'BIOS' partition with fdisk (option 3), NOT EFI/ESP partition.

Then, it magically becomes also regonized bz the Storage tool as 'bios_grub' and the selection as boot device becomes possible.

Not sure why the comment seems to suggest differently...